# Dividing 200 people in 3 unequal rooms and probability of certain combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 3 rooms (say 1, 2 and 3). Room 1 can take 50 people, room 2 can take 50 and room 3 can take 100. I understand that the number of ways of assigning 200 people to these 3 rooms is $200 \choose 50$$ 150 \choose 50$. The question is what is the probability that Alice (A) and Bob (B) end up in the same room while Charlotte (C) ends up in a different room.

**My solution**

I first divided the event $E$ = {A and B in same room, C in different room} in the disjoint events $E1$ = {{A and B in room 1, C in room 2} $\cup$ {A and B in room 1, C in room 3}}  , $E2$ = {{A and B in room 2, C in room 1} $\cup$ {A and B in room 2, C in room 3}} and $E3$ = {{A and B in room 3, C in room 1} $\cup$ {A and B in room 3, C in room 2}}.

I calculated the possible cases for E1 in the following way: $197 \choose 48$$149 \choose 49$
$+$ $197 \choose 47$ $149 \choose 50$. My reasoning for the case A and B in 1 while C in 2 was that I first pick the people that will make up room 1 alongside A and B (excluding C) and then pick the people that will make up room 2 alongside C (room 3 will then be uniquely determined). The reasoning for the case A and B in 1 while C in 3 was analogous.

Similar reasonings were employed to calculate the favorable cases for $E2$ and $E3$:

$|E2|$ = $197 \choose 49$$148 \choose 48$
$+$ $197 \choose 50$ $147 \choose 48$

$|E3|$ = $197 \choose 49$$148 \choose 50$
$+$ $197 \choose 50$ $147 \choose 49$

The probability was then simply calculated by summing the favorable cases for $E1$, $E2$ and $E3$ and finally dividing by the total number of cases.

I am wondering if this method is correct. Furthermore, if it is correct, I am wondering if there is a simpler method since this method requires dealing with awfully big numbers.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a typo in your formula for E1, I think. By symmetry, E2=E1, and the two terms for E3 are the same, which simplifies the arithmetic. Most of the factors cancel out, so not so big numbers

Comment: Rooms 1 and 2 have 50 seats each, and room 3 has 100 seats. Assign a seat to Alice (hint: it is room 3, or not room 3), then find the probability that Bob is assigned a seat in the same room while Charlotte is assigned a seat in a different room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rare probability problem, based on Combinatorics, where the problem is easier to attack by probability, rather than Combinatorics.

You have that :

- $(1/2)~$ of the time, Alice will be in either Room-1 or Room-2.
- $(1/2)~$ of the time, Alice will be in Room-3.

---

When Alice is in Room-1 or Room-2:

The probability that Bob is also in that room is $~\dfrac{50 - 1}{200 - 1} = \dfrac{49}{199}.$

Then, assuming that Bob is in the same room, the probability that Charlotte is not also in that room is $~1 - \dfrac{50 - 2}{200 - 2} = \dfrac{150}{198}.$

---

When Alice is in Room-3:

The probability that Bob is also in that room is $~\dfrac{100 - 1}{200 - 1} = \dfrac{99}{199}.$

Then, assuming that Bob is in the same room, the probability that Charlotte is not also in that room is $~1 - \dfrac{100 - 2}{200 - 2} = \dfrac{100}{198}.$

---

So, putting it all together, the probability that Alice and Bob are together, with Charlotte in a different room is

$$\left[ ~\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{49}{199} \times \frac{150}{198} ~\right] + \left[ ~\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{99}{199} \times \frac{100}{198} ~\right] \\
= \frac{1}{2 \times 199 \times 198} \times [ ~(49 \times 150) + (99 \times 100) ~].$$

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. The final answer is the same but this way is much simpler and more understandable. I think I was just set on solving it combinatorially without realizing probabilities were much easier.

Comment: @andripette Usually, it is the reverse.  That is, usually, if the probability problem involves Combinatorics, then Combinatorics is the way to go.  There are exceptions.